# On install create the database tables and insert not working - wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress

I created a function that creates tables in the Wordpress database on activation. I already checked that only this function generates the unexpected output error on activation. What is also strange is that the code creates and populates only the first table. But when I delete the part of the code that creates the first table, the following sql queries do not take effect. I read through all related post on the Internet and didn't find a solution. Can anyone help me out?

```
    function prtxgal_install(){
    global $wpdb;

    $prtx_getsettings = $wpdb->get_row( "SELECT * FROM " . $wpdb->prefix . "prtxgal_settings WHERE id = 1;" );


    if ($prtx_getsettings == NULL) {

        $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "prtxgal_settings";
        $table_name2 = $wpdb->prefix . "prtxgal_galleries";
        $table_name3 = $wpdb->prefix . "prtxgal_images";

        $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();

        require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );

        $sql = "CREATE TABLE $table_name (
        id mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        time timestamp DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
        outline_color text NOT NULL,
        desc_bg_color text NOT NULL,
        font_color text NOT NULL,
        file_path text NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY  (id)
        ) $charset_collate;";
        dbDelta( $sql );

        $sql = "CREATE TABLE $table_name2 (
        id mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        time timestamp DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
        name text NOT NULL,
        preview_image text NOT NULL,
        image_number text NOT NULL,
        order int(10) NOT NULL,
        published int(2) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY  (id)
        ) $charset_collate;";
        dbDelta( $sql );

        $sql = "CREATE TABLE $table_name3 (
        id mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        time timestamp DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
        gallery_id text NOT NULL,
        filename text NOT NULL,
        image_url text NOT NULL,
        thumb_url text NOT NULL,
        description text NOT NULL,
        alt text NOT NULL,
        order int(10) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY  (id)
        ) $charset_collate;";
        dbDelta( $sql );

        $wpdb->insert(
                $table_name,
                array(
                        'id' => 1,
                        'outline_color' => '#000000',
                        'desc_bg_color' => '#000000',
                        'font_color' => '#ffffff',
                        'file_path' => '/images/default.png'
                    )
                    );

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code the problem is order field name while running the sql order word is taken as order keyword due to that this is the doing the issue.

```
function prtxgal_install() {
    global $wpdb;
    $prtx_getsettings = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM " . $wpdb->prefix . "prtxgal_settings WHERE id = 1;");
    if ($prtx_getsettings == NULL) {

        $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "prtxgal_settings";
        $table_name2 = $wpdb->prefix . "prtxgal_galleries";
        $table_name3 = $wpdb->prefix . "prtxgal_images";

        $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();

        require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php';

        $sql = "CREATE TABLE $table_name (
        id mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        time timestamp DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
        outline_color text NOT NULL,
        desc_bg_color text NOT NULL,
        font_color text NOT NULL,
        file_path text NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY  (id)
        ) $charset_collate;";
        dbDelta($sql);

        $sql = "CREATE TABLE $table_name2 (
        id mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        time timestamp DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
        name text NOT NULL,
        preview_image text NOT NULL,
        image_number text NOT NULL,
        `order` int(10) NOT NULL,
        published int(2) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY  (id)
        ) $charset_collate;";
        dbDelta($sql);

        $sql = "CREATE TABLE $table_name3 (
        id mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        time timestamp DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
        gallery_id text NOT NULL,
        filename text NOT NULL,
        image_url text NOT NULL,
        thumb_url text NOT NULL,
        description text NOT NULL,
        alt text NOT NULL,
        `order` int(10) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY  (id)
        ) $charset_collate;";
        dbDelta($sql);

        $wpdb->insert(
            $table_name,
            array(
                'id' => 1,
                'outline_color' => '#000000',
                'desc_bg_color' => '#000000',
                'font_color' => '#ffffff',
                'file_path' => '/images/default.png',
            )
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't forget to close anything, I am new to stack overflow and my code pasted incomplete.

Comment: Yes the first table is created but the remaining two are  not, and I get "plugin generated 1746 characters of unexpected output ..." on plugin activation

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention the error message, but I think here is the problem.

The table is created once you activate the plugin, your SQL statement has risk of creating existing table. Change "`CREATE TABLE $table_nameX`" with "`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $table_nameX`", then try your code again.

Comment: it didn't help unfortunately, I am still getting unexpected output error and only the first query creates a table

Comment: (plugin generated 1746 characters of unexpected output ...), but when I delete this function everything goes fine.

Answer (score 0):

I partially solved the issue by pasting the queries directly to PHP MyAdmin. The problem was I probably used a forbidden word for my column name, that is, 'order'. I changed it to 'img_order' and now all tables are created correctly :) Yet I am still getting "plugin generated 226 characters of unexpected output ..." error

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with this and works well, great thanks for help.

```
function prtxgal_install(){
    global $wpdb;



        $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "prtxgal_settings";
        $table_name2 = $wpdb->prefix . "prtxgal_galleries";
        $table_name3 = $wpdb->prefix . "prtxgal_images";

        $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();

        require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );

        $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $table_name (
        id mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        time timestamp DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
        outline_color text NOT NULL,
        desc_bg_color text NOT NULL,
        font_color text NOT NULL,
        file_path text NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY  (id)
        ) $charset_collate;";
        dbDelta( $sql );

        $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $table_name2 (
        id mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        time timestamp DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
        name text NOT NULL,
        preview_image text NOT NULL,
        image_count text NOT NULL,
        gal_order int(10) NOT NULL,
        published int(9) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY  (id)
        ) $charset_collate;";
        dbDelta( $sql );

        $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $table_name3 (
        id mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        time timestamp DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
        gallery_id text NOT NULL,
        filename text NOT NULL,
        image_url text NOT NULL,
        thumb_url text NOT NULL,
        description text NOT NULL,
        alt text NOT NULL,
        img_order int(10) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY  (id)
        ) $charset_collate;";
        dbDelta( $sql );

        $wpdb->insert(
                $table_name,
                array(
                        'id' => 1,
                        'outline_color' => '#000000',
                        'desc_bg_color' => '#000000',
                        'font_color' => '#ffffff',
                        'file_path' => '/images/default.png'
                    )
                    );




}
```